# Unable to add search or filter functionality to HTML table populated with fetched data. - Django REST API/Svelte

Tags: javascript, html, django, fetch-api, svelte

I am trying to add search and filter functionality to a HTML table, which I populated with fetched data.

I am using a fetch request inside a Svelte component to retrieve data from a Django REST API. This part is successful, the data populates the table as desired with no issues.

[Populated Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axaKh.png)

I have made several attempts to add search and filter functionality to the table. Upon research I've discovered that because the fetch request is asynchronous, the  values are not stored on the DOM, thereby when I run a querySelectAll method, an empty nodelist is returned.

From there I've made several attempts to try and store the fetched data locally and use that local data to populate the table, but none of my attempts have worked.

I've tried pushing the fetched data to an empty list, then using that list to populate the table.
I've tried using innerHTML methods to populate the table, as well as a few other attempts that didn't work.

please see code snippets below

Svelte component script tag

```
<script>

import { onMount } from 'svelte';
const endpoint = 'http://localhost:8000/testresults/';
export let results = []

const load = async function () {
    const jsonResponse = await fetch(endpoint);
    const data = await jsonResponse.json(); 
    results = data
}

onMount(load);


</script>
```

Svelte component HTML

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search"/>
</div>

<div class="table-div">
    <table class="content-table" id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID<span class="icon-arrow">&uparrow;</span></th>
                <th>Test Name<span class="icon-arrow">&uparrow;</span></th>
                <th>Test DateTime<span class="icon-arrow">&uparrow;</span></th>
                <th>Engineer<span class="icon-arrow">&uparrow;</span></th>
                <th>Driver<span class="icon-arrow">&uparrow;</span></th>
                <th>Cell<span class="icon-arrow">&uparrow;</span></th>
                <th>Vehicle<span class="icon-arrow">&uparrow;</span></th>
                <th>IWR<span class="icon-arrow">&uparrow;</span></th>
                <th>RMMSE<span class="icon-arrow">&uparrow;</span></th>
                <th>Total c0<span class="icon-arrow">&uparrow;</span></th>
                <th>Total c02<span class="icon-arrow">&uparrow;</span></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {#each results as result }
            <tr>
                <td> {result.id}</td>
                <td> {result.test_name}</td>
                <td> {result.test_datetime}</td>
                <td> {result.engineer}</td>
                <td> {result.driver}</td>
                <td> {result.cell}</td>
                <td> {result.vehicle_id}</td>
                <td> {result.iwr}</td>
                <td> {result.rmsse}</td>
                <td> {result.total_co}</td>
                <td> {result.total_co2}</td>
            </tr>
            {/each}
        </tbody>
            
        </table>
</div>
```

I'm very new to frontend development so any insight or new approaches would be greatly appreciated.